# List all Harvard University lecturers from Wikidata using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia, wikidata

I want to query all lecturers of the Harvard University with their names and academic titles.

This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT ?item ?degree WHERE { 
  ?item <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P803> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q13371>. 
  ?degree <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P512> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q13371>.
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't find any records.

One can play around [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Fdegree%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2FP803%3E%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ13371%3E.%20%0A%20%20%3Fdegree%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2FP512%3E%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ13371%3E.%0A%7D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several attempts it seems to me that Wikidata doesn't contain the data you are looking for.

First of all, your triple pattern for `?degree` seems wrong. The relationship should be *a person* "has a degree" *degree*; what you have is *a degree* "has a degree" *Harvard University*.

A query you can try is

```
SELECT ?person ?degree ?relationship WHERE { 
  ?person <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/P512> ?degree .
  ?person ?relationship <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q13371>. 
}
```

This selects all persons for which a degree is known and their relationship to Harvard University. You can see that the only relationships returned are "conferred by" or "educated at", neither of which is a "is a lecturer at" relationship you are looking for. Reversing to `<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q13371> ?rel ?person` doesn't help either.

So unless there's another property for academic degree that we missed, I don't think Wikidata can give you the answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt Wikidata has the information you want, but you can at least get a list of people that Wikidata thinks have been employed by Harvard. Given their "notability" rules, they're likely to be almost all professors (with perhaps a few senior administrators thrown in).

This query will give you a little over 3,000 people:

```
SELECT ?itemLabel WHERE { 
  ?item <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P108> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q13371>. 

    SERVICE wikibase:label {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    }
}
```